# Tomcat7 (localhost:8080): 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am running tomcat7 within Eclipse. When I set `Tomcat/Properties/Location: /Servers/Tomcat v7.0` Server at localhost.server, I CAN reach `localhost:8080`, but gets `404` error on my sites (`localhost:8080/mysite/user/adduser`). When I set Location: `[workspace metabase]`, I get `404` error on both `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/mysite/user/adduser`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Web Module is added to Tomcat and has the expected path. To do so:

- Open the Servers tab (Window -> Show View -> Servers).
- Double-click the Tomcat Server (a new window will open)
- On this window, check the Modules tabs.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow the Modules/Path got changed. Any idea what caused it?

Comment: I'm not sure. When you use web servers within Eclipse, it creates a configuration folder called Servers with one subfolder for each web server. In your case, there is probably a folder called "Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config". The Modules tab edits the server.xml of your Tomcat. You were probably editing configurations that changed that file.